# Мягкий знак в окончании

Tags: мягкий-знак

Может ли мягкий знак входить в состав окончаний?

Answer (score 2):

> Может ли мягкий знак входить в состав окончаний?

Может  — у глаголов в личных формах:

*я ид-**у**, ты ид-**ёшь...***

Плюс (в ряде учебников) окончанием называют и ***-ть*** в инфинитивах.

**[См.:](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200100608)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте текст в виде текста, а не изображения.